# how to change yocto desktop to gnome,xfce…?

Tags: xfce, desktop, yocto

I'm new to Yocto project. I can build image for intel-corei7-64 (UEFI and Legacy). Now, how can I change default desktop? I found meta-gnome , meta-xfce layer in openembedded layer index, I know how to add layers in `build/conf/bblayers.conf`, but how change it to default desktop after boot? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! I should use `bitbake core-image-minimal-xfce` command for building XFCE image. and not to forget to add meta-xfce and it's dependencies.